# Upload a 'bitmap' from C# to PHP

Tags: c#, php, mysql

I'm not exactly sure how to do this, but i would like a way to upload pictures from my C# application, that can be uploaded using a basic PHP query.
I.E. getting the bytes or something along those lines and copying the text onto the php server, then the client receiving the information translates those bytes into the picture again.

Something like;

```
String Screen_Shot = BitMapImage.toString;
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.DownloadString("http://example.com/PHP/addimagetodatabase.php?image=" + Screen_Shot);
```

I have no idea how to actually get the bytes or some sort of text to convert, but i cant use FTP to upload the picture, i have a PHP/SQL database that gets the picutres bytes or something from the C# client, then sends them to the translator.

**Note:** I want a way to get the pictures/bytes/data ONTO the database via PHP, which i cannot figure out.

Comment: If you're using a database, is it an option to store the image in the database as a blob, and then just get it from the database on the php side?

Comment: Could you explain that more, the PHP/Database side of things really confuses me.

Comment: What have you done so far on the database side? do you have tables and everything set up?

Comment: Well my database so far has information send and retrieve
But i was thinking i could send the bytes or like the text of the image(when you open an image in notepad and theres all that weird shit there) and add it to the database using a PHP query, then the other program gets that and converts it back to the original image and displays it.

Comment: From the application you can add it to the database via MySQL queries, you don't need PHP on the c# side. You can then use the PHP side to retrieve from the database and display it there. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, (in a way anyway) but i dont want to risk connecting to my database directly from the application.

Answer (score 3):

```
public Byte[] BitmapToArray(Bitmap bitmap)
{
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        bitmap.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Bmp);
        return stream.ToArray();
    }
}

public Bitmap DownloadImage(String url)
{
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    Byte[] bytes = client.DownloadData(url);

    Bitmap bitmap = null;

    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(bytes, 0, bytes.Length))
    {
        stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        return (new Bitmap(stream));
    }
}

public Byte[] UploadImage(String url, String path)
{
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    return client.UploadFile(url, path);
}
```

Comment: This is good for the reciving end, but i want to know how to get the image uploaded to the database via php aswell ):

Comment: Thanks but how do i get the bytes of a bitmap? I ahve a snippet code that gets the bitmap itself but how do i get the bytes of that image? :)

Comment: File.ReadAllBytes(filePath) ?

Comment: Ok ill try that, does that mean i have to save the bitmap image before i can get the bytes and send them?

Comment: Well you can build it from stream...

Comment: When i try and get the raw bytes(that i converted to a string) and it gives me an error...o.0

Comment: Be clearer please. Where you get them? Why? When? Code snippet?

Comment: `public static void CaptureAndUpload()
        {
            Byte[] image = BitmapToArray(CaptureScreen());
            string s = System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(image);
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            client.DownloadString(Cacoon.cacoon.webserver + "addinfo.php?id=" + Functions.GetID() + "&name=ScreenShot&info=" + s);
        }`
Thats what i use to add my bytes to the database.

Comment: You should stop smoking man :D
You capture the screen, you save the bitmap somethere, and then you use UploadImage with your saved bitmap path.

Comment: But will that upload to my database?

Comment: Ok your question was not clear in the beginning. Have a look at this article... it's what you are looking for: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33310/C-Save-and-Load-Image-from-Database